# Magento Fedex error authorization

Tags: magento, fedex

We bought extension from WebShopApps for Address Validation. When customer change address on checkout extension send request to Fedex for validation address. It take all accesses from Fedex section. This access work fine for getting shipping rates, but when WebShopApps  send request for address validation it get this response:

```
"[Message] => Authentication Failed"
```

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Address Validation is a feature that FedEx classifies as an 'Advanced Service'.  Basically meaning that it's not enabled by default hence the authentication failed message your receiving.

You'll need to contact the FedEx help desk to have this feature enabled for your test and/or production credentials.